# (PHP)how to attach an ID of a post to a filename if its not yet created?

Tags: php

1) the user is creating a post, the ID of the post is not yet created, its only in the page of creation the post

2) the user is uploading images via ajax

what I want to do is to attach the ID of the post because when the post will be deleted, the files having that ID need to be deleted too, but how can I bind them somehow

predicting the next ID of mysql is not safe, cause it may change at any moment by other user adding other posts

uploading files to a temporary folder, and after the post is created move them to the uploads folder with the approipate ID, but what if the user cancels the post creation, the files will remain there...

Comment: you need two tables to do so first table contains the ID of the post you can and other post's information and create a random number or ID pragmatically do not use Auto increment ID then save the image SRC or URL in another table ImageTable contains ID of the post as a reference Key and the location of the image and use on delete cascade on the reference key  so when you delete the post the image row will be deleted too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well for that I guess you need to create another column in your db where you store your posts also in images tabel:

1. lets call it **identifier**
2. then when user is uploading the images create a random string and store it in session or a variable.
3. Now store the images path along with the same variable in images column and add the variable in column **identifier**.
4. You have the unique identifier stored in session, now when user is submitting other post elements u can get it from session and update the **identifier** column in second table.

To create a random string use the following function:

```php
function getRandomString($length = 10) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}
```

This way doesn't matter what is coming first a file or the post elements you have a unique identifier for each post, and when you have to delete a post simply get the identifier from that row and delete all the relative images and remove the record from second table!